# override memory allocation of global variables

Tags: c++, memory-management, g++, global-variables, mmap

I need to assign a unique virtual page to each global object. For heap-allocated objects, I could override `malloc/new` calls and use `mmap` appropriately. But global objects like `static struct {...} instance1;` are allocated memory by the compiler itself in the data segment. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Put them in specific sections and assign them virtual addresses in the linker script.

A more c++-ish way would be to use placement new to allocate them.

Comment: _"use placement new to allocate them"_ — It doesn't sound right. AFAIK, placement new does not allocate. Instead, it initializes objects in already allocated storage.

Comment: @DanielLangr You have to "allocate" the storage in whatever you use to initialize the virtual memory mapping. The placement new just handles the initialization.

Comment: @DanielLangr Is there any less-manual/complicated way like maybe some compiler attributes like `__aligned__` or something?

Comment: Oh, if you only want each object to take a page then `alignas(4096)` but that will add a ton of padding to your type.